# Search JSON response to find and deserialize JSON object

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm attempting to deserialize a JSON object with the Jackson objectMapper. The problem I'm having is that this target object can be wrapped in a variety of other JSON, including some but not all fields matching my target. For example, I'm trying to deserialize and object such as:

```
public class Dog {  
    private String name;    
    private int age;
    private String color;  
}
```

From a JSON object such as:

```
{
"type":"animal",
"name":"pet",
"object":{
  "name":"Rex",
  "age":4,
  "color":"brown"
  }
}
```

Or it could be from an object such as:

```
{
"pet-dog":{
  "name":"Rex",
  "age":4,
  "color":"brown"
  }
}
```

I also have @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true) set, since my objects sometimes have optional fields that are not important.

The problem is two fold, first I need to unwrap arbitrary JSON to find my target object, the arbitrary JSON will vary significantly between requests. Second, the arbitrary JSON to unwrap, may match one or more of the field names of my target object (ex "name" in example above).

The approach I want is to search the JSON for an object that contains a set of required fields, then attempt to desterilize that as my object.  But no idea how to achieve that....

I have tried leveaging ObjectMapper with annotations for required properties:
`@JsonProperty(value = "user", required = true)`.

Comment: Do you want a solution that dosen't parse the object manually? Or are you looking for an automated, library specific aproach?

Comment: Ideally automated library specific, but my current thinking is that parsing and searching will need to be more manual object parsing, then passing some sort of pointer to the deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is to deserialize the whole JSON into `JsonNode` first. Then use JSON library to search and transform the `JsonNode` before converting to POJO.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**JSON 1**

```
Josson ex1 = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "\"type\":\"animal\"," +
    "\"name\":\"pet\"," +
    "\"object\":{" +
    "  \"name\":\"Rex\"," +
    "  \"age\":4," +
    "  \"color\":\"brown\"" +
    "  }" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = ex1.getNode("*[value[name!=null & age!=null & color!=null]]");
Dog dog = Josson.readValueFor(node, Dog.class);
```

**JSON 2**

```
Josson ex2 = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "\"pet-dog\":{" +
    "  \"name\":\"Rex\"," +
    "  \"age\":4," +
    "  \"color\":\"brown\"" +
    "  }" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = ex2.getNode("*[value[name!=null & age!=null & color!=null]]");
Dog dog = Josson.readValueFor(node, Dog.class);
```